# How can I import existing password into Pulumi?

Tags: pulumi

I'm trying to import an existing system into Pulumi, in particular I wish to support generating passwords for any new stacks, but using the existing password for the existing stack. Is this possible?

I've tried the following as per https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/random/randompassword/#import

```
pulumi new azure-python
pulumi plugin install resource random 3.1.1
pulumi import random:index/randomPassword:RandomPassword password Password123!
```

This gives the error `random:index/randomPassword:RandomPassword resource 'password' has a problem: Required attribute is not set. Examine values at 'RandomPassword.Length'`. This makes sense but it's not clear from the docs I've read that it is possible to set the value of an attribute when importing a resource.

This is using the latest version of Pulumi (2.32.1) which I'm using local login for.

This is actually for me writing a training exercise so if the answer is too unpleasant (e.g. exporting the state and reimporting it with the real password) it's probably not worth doing.

Comment: This apparently is fixed as of v4.12.0, but I haven't verified https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-random/issues/160#issuecomment-1464364348